# Scipy multivariate_normal cdf differs from the manual computing one

Tags: python, scipy

I am computing value of normal distribution cdf in two ways:

1. Using scipy library:

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
from scipy.special import erf, erfc

sigma = 0.793387

one = multivariate_normal(1.0, sigma)
one.cdf(0.0)
```

Output: 0.13078590311690458

2. Manual computing

```
1.0 /2 * (1.0 + erf(-1.0 / np.sqrt(2) / sigma))
```

Output: 0.10375913672098108

They differ significantly.

I am using this formula:
[image]

Can you tell me, please, where could it be a mistake?

UPD: when I use `norm` from `scipy.stats` it shows answer from the manual computations:

```
norm.cdf(0.0, 1.0, sigma)
```

Output: 0.10375913672098103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cdf of the `multivariate_normal` takes a covariation matrix as a parameter, where dispersions (but not deviation) should be on the diagonal. So there is a correct way of using the cdf:

```
one = multivariate_normal(1.0, sigma * sigma)
```